# How do I return dynamic column stored procedure results with ASP.NET Web Api OData provider?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm banging my head against the wall with this one.

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET Web API OData service for a customer. **The data returned comes from a SQL Server stored procedure that returns data with different structure every time (the columns may change on every execution).**

I tried to do it with an entities model but of course - the whole point of EF is a pre-known data model and I found it impossible to get it to work.

I also tried using ADO.NET - get the stored procedure's data using a `SqlDataReader` and building a `DataTable` object with the columns (that change every time the stored procedure is executed) but I keep getting configuration errors, http errors and it looks like I'm not getting it right. Getting the stored procedure data worked but something with getting the data to be returned to the OData client doesn't work properly.

Google for several hours and tried several approaches but nothing works. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (maybe it's too old a version?)

Did anyone succeed in getting variable structured data to be returned from a Web Api OData controller? Any sample projects that show how to do it?

My client is Excel (importing from an OData feed).

Comment: What specific version of OData are you using. If you're still in VS2013 I assume .Net framework, but I am hoping ODataLib > v7.  Does the schema really change with every request? or is there some sort of pattern, perhaps based on the parameters that mean we could model with a little bit of known structure. Some examples of the output types (even hypothetical) will help illustrate your request but will help make the solution easier to follow.

Comment: You know VS 2022 Community edition is free right ;) Your productivity will improve if you use the latest IDE, even if you are bound to the older frameworks

Comment: I'm using VS2013 with OData 6.2  but can upgrade to a newer version if it helps resolving the problem. In terms of the columns in the returned results - there is a subset of columns that are always  returned and a subset the changes based on an argument passed to the stored procedure.

Comment: I have seen some articles talking about OData "open types" that may a a possible solution because they allow a subset of dynamic columns to be added to an entity or complex type returned in the results but I failed to find a sample that shows how to do it with a stored procedure.

Comment: Open type support is the feature you need, but v7 of OData Lib fixes a lot of compatibility issues. Upgrade the NuGet package to v7 while we put together an SP walkthrough, the MS learn docs do not do this feature justice at all

Comment: Please edit your post with an example that shows 2 of the output types. There are a few tricks that make this easier but they come with caveats, I want to offer you a solution that will work for your situation. Don't worry, there's no trade secrets here, none of these ideas are every really new, just recycled or shared experiences.